# Readify Where clause can't contain Intersect()?

Tags: neo4jclient

I have objects that contain a list that is stored in Neo4j just fine, but I'm unable to do an intersect in the neo4j query (I get an object not defined exception in the Readify expression code). I've had to resort to bringing back all the results and doing the intersection outside of the cypher query. Each list is a List and I am just calling Intersect() on them.

The Readify expression doesnt support them though. Anyone know a way around this ?

```
Match()
.Where( (u) => u.myList.Intersect(otherList).Count() == 1)
.Return (... );
```

Comment: The client driver can only support what Cypher supports. The best way to approach these problems is to work out the answer in Cypher first, then come back and translate it to C#. Last I looked, Cypher doesn't have an intersect statement like this, so it's going to look different.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tatham !

I ended up solving this by using "WHERE in x" subarray matching. I just created the where clause on the fly and pass this as a string to the neo client. Forgot the WHERE function could take a string OR a lamda